# How to add .Net Framework Nuget into .Net Standard Class Library Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-framework-version

I have one custom Nuget Package build by Dot Net Framework 4.6.1 and I want to integrate this Nuget into my Dot Net Standard Class library project.  After Installing the Dot Net Framework Nuget package via 'Manage Nuget Package' I was trying to access the class from my Dot Net Standard Class library project, unfortunately, I couldn't access Dependencies Class's. I have discovered that there are many possibilities to add Dot Net Framework 4.6.1 Nuget into ASP.Dot Net, WPF, or relevant projects. But I couldn't find anything to integrate Dot Net Framework 4.6.1 Nuget into Dot Net Standard Class Library Projects. So that I have to ask here. If anyone can mentor please it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of the .NET standard library are you using? the .NET Framework 4.6.1 is supported in .NET standard from 1.4 to 2.0

Comment: "unfortunately, I couldn't access Dependencies Class's" probably because those dependencies are built in a version of .NET Framework before 4.6.1.

Comment: I am using .Net Standard 2.0. and the Nuget Package .Net Framework  4.6.1